# Minecraft server in ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, server, ati, minecraft

I've been living in a hotel do to a house fire.
I have just tried to setup a server for some of my friends to connect and it doens't seem to work.
I port forwarded the port 27015 and set that in the server.properties file.
I also set my ip(192.168.2.104) in that same file.

Everything should checkout ok but it doens't, I go to a site like http://www.canyouseeme.org and it says "Error: I could not see your service on 66.192.111.230 on port (27015)"
Yes my server is running.

Can you help me?

PC Specs:
Intel Core I5 3470 Quad 3.2Ghz
4GBs DDR3 RAM
ATI Radeon HD 5450 1GB DDR3

Comment: And the hotel allows you to run a server over their network?

Comment: When you say you port forwarded, are you saying that the hotel did this for you as the hotel router is where you would port forward. Also most hotels block most ports. I normally had to call the hotel reception to even open a simple VPN port

Comment: Is the port open on the hotel router, and allowed in ubuntu using UFW?

Answer (score 0):

Since it's just for some friends, try using Hamachi.  There's a nice gui for it called Haguichi.

First, download [Hamachi](https://secure.logmein.com/labs/#HamachiforLinux) and install the .deb for your system.

Then, type the following into the terminal.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/haguichi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install haguichi
```

You should be able to open it and create a network for your friends.  Just give them your hamachi ip (usually is 25.*.*.*).  No port forwarding necessary!